# Unit testing store.mapDispatchToProps in Stencil with Redux using Jest

Tags: redux, jestjs, stenciljs

I am struggling to unit test the store in the componentWillLoad() lifecycle.

I have tried following this guide: https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store

component.tsx

```
  @Prop({ context: "store" }) store: Store;

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.store.mapDispatchToProps(this, { updateStep });
  }
```

spec.ts

```
   const middlewares = [thunk];
   const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

   const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({ type: updateStep});

   it('should test componentWillLoad', () => { 

    const initialState = {};
    const store = mockStore(initialState);

    store.dispatch(mapDispatchToProps());
    const actions = store.updateStep();
    const expectedPayload = { type: updateStep};
    expect(actions).toEqual([expectedPayload]);

});
```

I get the following error atm: TypeError: mockStore is not a function